# django form to python script

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I would like to know how to get the web user response (in model.charfield) and turn it into a python script variable. For example:

**In subimit/models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

my_choices1 = [(1, "bcc (default)"), (2, "gasteiger"), (5, "user")]
my_choices2 = [(1, "GAFF (default)"), (2, "AMBER")]

class Submition(models.Model):
        charge_method = models.CharField(choices=my_choices1, max_length=20, blank=False, default=1)
        net_charge = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=1)
        multiplicity = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=1)
        atom_type = models.CharField(choices=my_choices2, max_length=20, blank=False, default=1)
```

**In python script:**

```
from submit.models import Submition

def run():
    a = Submition.objects
```